# Error when using "do shell script"

Tags: applescript, macos

I'm using a MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid-2014) running El Capitan. I'm trying to create a script that checks if my computer is open or not, and I'm using this:

`ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState | grep '"AppleClamshellState"' | cut -f2 -d"=""`

I tested this in Terminal and it works fine, so I add `do shell script` in front of it to run it in AppleScript. But when I do, it gives me this:

`Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier.`

Please help!

Comment: I updated my answer to use `grep` and `cut` however I'd stick with `awk`!

Comment: See the Note at the bottom of my answer to shed some light on the quoting issues surrounding complex commands used with `do shell script`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of piping to `grep` and `cut`, just use `awk`.

```
do shell script "ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState | awk -F \" = \" '/AppleClamshellState/ {print $2}'"
```

- `-F \" = \"` makes the separator: `=` (space = space)
- `/AppleClamshellState/` Search for: `AppleClamshellState`
- `{print $2}` Prints *Yes* or *No* depending on what's returned for:`AppleClamshellState`
- E.g `"AppleClamshellState" = No` prints `No`

[image]

You can also use:

```
do shell script "ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState | grep 'AppleClamshellState' | cut -d'=' -f2"
```

However there will be a leading space in front of *Yes* or *No* as `cut` only handles a single character for the deliminator.

[image]

Note: The *command text* portion of `do shell script`, e.g. `do shell script "uptime"` must be double-quoted. So when the *command text string* itself is using double-quotes within the *string*, one should substitute a single-quote `'` wherever possible and if double-quotes must be used within the *string* then escape them with a backslash `\`.

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: Works fine for me!

Comment: OK, now I have `set myVar to "do shell script "ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState | awk -F \" = \" '/AppleClamshellState/ {print $2}'""`, and it gives me `A identifier can’t go after this “"”.` higlighting `ioreg`.

Comment: Your command is malformed! There should be no `"` in front of `do` and you have an extra `"` at the end.  Copy and paste my code exactly as is and it should work!

Comment: Just realised that right before you commented. Thanks for your help! :-)